# Images from html template email not showing in Gmail mobile

Tags: css, http

so I started doing HTML email template with using the table form or the tr>td codes and stuff, my template mostly combine with small text and mostly graphic my main concern is that when I test my email template in my pc It jus work fine also. the images and graphic ay pretty responsive but when I test it on my mobile the image is not even loading even the place holders for it does bother to load I really confuse

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Application Accepted </title>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@200&display=swap');
    .body{
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        font-family:'Manrope', sans-serif;
    }
    .table{
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    .td{
        padding: 0;
    }
    .img{
        border: 0;
    }
    .wrapper{
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .main{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        border-spacing: 0;
        font-family:'Manrope',sans-serif;
        color: #FDB833;
    }
    .Logo{
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .content{
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 0;   
    }
    .logo{
        text-align: right;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
        .content .img{
            width: 600px!important;
            max-width: 600px!important;
        }
        .Logo .img{
            width: 400px!important;
            max-width: 400px!important;
        }
      
    }

    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <center class="wrapper">
        <table class="main" width= 100%>
            
    <!--header-->
     <tr>
         <td>
             <table width="100%">
                 <tr>
                     <td class="Logo">
                         <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dydWcJy6wrBvml0hAPEw12f9CiHgEEf9MN0vFDkrEPx7i0bzCpdq4_WqDhC9mGCeMv3CsWnq2BH1jgaDXsEhCd9DWaRMu1LBPJCCCWsnt9NrRyucZf5qeJz1wOMUsNjZ2rl4CITbE4GXf1_FudMM473BriHc_gILDFmQ4qdD0rUeJkfDVdXFns0bJUA0HqPFh9nyWoNbSe5g5SHTulxEYCemom23K-5_ld1zMvX_AkZwC-brRTN4gTAHk_eWAi6wbdXzVujAhc6_IrYByYd3HMqhD8WJBe8qi9FsR95AlX1ncMVvzXwEmd4Ozz_KvSxf2BXi8tWTZJc6pUEhkVTlCOHrqgiVP13HzYOEhUol1_3X3fJUD6IxTcKzI5kGBA4byp_47cQWqnSRVx_9t5QH3dVEzJjsorPEH19JhQ54NSdhoQg3KkHsJzS0lJTLIfDdP8EQv90kGWKh8Up7B4XLn0z0Hycp_WciuaEupO_ykCDFrPhRNk74vjWyo8mMhxzkQEvRf2Jvvmn8-yzp8B_AB9J4SmbnUXehwabt13SSgK8QN70cYzpjij3HX7ABng0kXiyVH_pGlcXruVNokaisVr4lpCHGUgsTuTLC83A9iEsoNPuViaYJPQm_Rs-tvYS2jJy-ejXCd8W5FynfxibIL9CXynSzqEWQKlGBtc2LHDfcHowtXMuEVddGUCJ9lg=w400-h113-no?authuser=0"
                         alt="" width="200px">
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td width=100% height= 20px style="background-color: #007F5F;"></td>
     </tr>
    <!--content-->
    <tr>
        
            
                    <td class="content">
                        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mU8vN1xEsyHYAbV7IZZEbvpxRijXbTf7B2OlX_0kKDKTIWDeREXmRymFksPekBaVkX-fZ9MwYlGTH4roD9K0qzu8LHpyfOJwJ54fZO9m6O6Cl4jn1ErWRNqEcRMXNr3LescX20M-lTDsiiMrjik5fiPKoKPiy-WxsEDP3r3VtQllkE4ISTjwSrTSYbDBawi2Hx-2VAJSL34CZwDAeIICqcQSxJPD5JCE1FEejrGCdQPzrYr7tUpUyfygTn5_5SOoNHvCbnZW3GsnMzQ4nSqWyFTZF1qrmN1tlVlAbL6lVSsF_V9QY5xRqhaxjtyky6kBNxAXBjU6QX4WlpFD-8Dj2hMDM9X9ckzMuZWuju5C_bKni1bw1OpsYKyO0lyiNamABd5l8rrkRVFK7Z_5gz3KJJYsBqcSn97hmhxjkgQjt0HJwfEIbd_H5bKGcl3GikiCNOsNY5sb_L7c6mx65y_vlKln4DJ25jk927_t6VM0aCZUMah1KrbcQdqUvopeDD0vp008cnREa15_17waa3_hZD1yJwzmFEmtmOq_Z7UItGr5rWIvPCZfQFznX-k6znGJ7xr7i-MGZihGplciBV-5rn6ncMjXzEkd-JQvQbOcM8HbJFZOiLNDYaJPPJYWV4hgNJi9ueuCjPmoVXLsdS7PfqcxhT4Kqse6SviuXwktYziddS_quS_EjrJexDrImg=w495-h695-no?authuser=0"
                        alt=""  width= auto style="max-width: 600px;">
                       
                    </td>
                
    </tr>
    <!--footer-->
    <tr>
        
                    <td class="footer" style="background-color: #007F5F; padding: 15px;">
                        <p style="text-align: left;font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">Courtesy:</p>
                        <p style="text-align: left;font-size: 10px;"> Approved by the St.Jerome School Administration and Club Committee<br>
                        Valid only for Academic year 2020-2021</p>
                        

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</center>
</body>
```

this my code for it I also the check the sizing if that the case yet it seems it's not, I am really new in coding and this is not even my forte.

Comment: Sounds a bit simplistic I know, but is your email client set up to show images (mine never is).

Comment: yes it is it just not working in gmail app but in desktop its working fine